# How do you know your node baker, endorser, accuser is running properly?

Tags: node, baker, endorser, accuser

Before the update my Tezos baker was running fine, the accuser when running would update every minute or so with a line that displayed in the terminal, the baker and endorser did not have anything displayed in their terminal, but when my time to endorse came up, it took it and displayed the endorsement. After the Edo update, the node runs, but the endorser, accuser and baker all just say node is bootstrapped and then it just sits there, silent and running, but no indicator anything is happening. So I assumed it was running, and then today I missed an endorsement. How do I know its all running properly **before** missing endorsements?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure you're running PtEdo2Zk tezos-baker and tezos-endorser instead of PtEdoTez. Your tezos-baker should at least provide low priority baking rights.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start baker/endorser/accuser, run `export TEZOS_LOG="* -> debug"` That will output much more information, like you were used to.  You probably did this when you launched 007 but forgot to redo when you started 008.